# .JSON file returns data which doesn't exist

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a .JSON file which contains info for every user in a discord server (Here to show you guys I only have 1 users data in the file).

The file looks like this:

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "u": "224906648890638337",
            "m": 89,
            "lvl": 0,
            "score": 28,
            "captcha": false,
            "captchacode": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

When a new user is detected, it should look through the file and check whether the user's data is already in the file. My code for that is:

```
with open("leveling_system/db.json", "r") as f:
        db = json.load(f)

# Creating New User #
for line in db:
    print(line)
for user in db["user"]:
    user_id = user["u"]
    if str(member.id) == str(user_id):
        print("user already in server")
        return
    else:
        db.setdefault("user", [])
        db["user"].append({
            "u": str(member.id),
            "m": 0,
            "lvl": 0,
            "score": 0,
            "captcha": False,
            "captchacode": code
        })

with open("leveling_system/db.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(db, f, indent=4)
```

But when a user joins that doesn't have data in the .JSON file it still says their data is in the file and when I return that key it gives me: `{'u': '742466798204616734', 'm': 0, 'lvl': 0, 'score': 0, 'captcha': False, 'captchacode': 616879}` even though no changes were made to the file and the file remains empty.

So why is it claiming that data exists in the file? Thanks!

Comment: Is this the full code? The code you posted will _always_ write to the file after adding a new user - I don't see a reason why the file would remain empty. What code is responsible for checking if the new user is present in the JSON file?

Comment: Your code adds the new user *once for each existing user*. You should only add the new user once you have verified that *none* of the existing users match. Currently, you add the new user after the *first* of the existing users does not match.

Comment: oh ok thx @MisterMiyagi ill change that

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that fixed it if u want u can create an asnwer for that and ill accept it

Comment: The point of adding and accepting an answer is to make a knowledge base entry for other people to use. I'd be astonished if the next person to have the problem "JSON file returns data which doesn't exist" will be helped by the q/a pair; there are too many different ways to have a problem that manifests as unexpected output values. (Given that, I'd suggest deleting the question, unless it can be clarified to have a title meaningful enough that the next person to find it in search results will likely have it _actually help them with whatever problem they're having_).